# How to pass connection details in Celery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

How using Celery can I add user and password connection details to my broker. I'm **not using the Django framework** but just Python 3.

I have tried this:

```
app = Celery('tasks',
             broker='sqs://123:123',
             )

app.connection(
    userid="23",
    password="123",
    transport_options="{'region': 'eu-west-1'}"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `config_from_object` method. From [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.config_from_object):

> Reads configuration from object, where object is either an object or
>   the name of a module to import.

For example:

**`celeryconfig.py`:**

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'amqp'
BROKER_USER = 'user'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'password'
BROKER_HOST = 'remote.server.com'
BROKER_PORT = 123
#...
```

in module:

```
app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```